# Installation error : pip install gTTS (Google-Text-To-Speech) error

Tags: python, failed-installation, google-text-to-speech

Getting syntax error while running the following command on terminal:

> > > pip install gTTS
> > >         File "", line 1
> > >           pip install gTTS
> > >                     ^

[image]

Comment: the syntax error is due to running a `bash` command in the `python` interpreter. `exit()` out of python, then execute the command `pip install gTTS` from the bash command prompt `$` where you previously entered `python`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mentioned in my reply to sehafoc I tried running the command from shell and started getting another error "no module name pip", so I installed pip by running following commands:

1. Downloaded pip script
       $ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py > get-pip.py
2. Executed the pip script by running following command
       $ sudo python get-pip.py
3. Install gTTS module
       $ sudo pip install gTTS

Answer (score 2):

That's not how you run pip... You run it from the *system* shell like this

```
> pip install gTTS
```

or

```
> python -m pip install gTTS
```

If you want to run it from inside a script, or a *python* shell you do it like this

```
import pip

def install(package):
    pip.main(['install', package])

# Example
if __name__ == '__main__':
    install('gTTS')
```

Comment: Thanks Sehafoc, I tried it from the shell as below and it give me another error:  no module name pip so I had to install pip and it worked fine. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Rajat, Sure thing buddy.

Answer (score 1):

If you had installed **Anaconda IDE**, the installation gets much hassle-free as it eliminates the headaches of trying to figure out which version/release of package X is compatible with which version/release of package Y.

Just **open the Conda prompt shell** and type the following command and hit `Enter`:

```
pip install gTTS
```

Voila! The package will be successfully installed in a jiffy!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use your pip on your cmd. But first thing, you have to install your pip with syntax:

```
python -m install pip
```

And don't forget to add python to your path, and then type this syntax to your cmd

```
python -m pip install gtts
```

and your gtts will dowloaded automatically